# define authorized values for a Schema's field

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Is it possible in Mongoose, to define authorized values for a specific field ?
For example my field "style", would only be allowed to be set to "jazz", "blues" or "rock"

```
var artistSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    style: {
        type: String
        // only allow values "jazz", "blues", "rock"
    }
});
```

Comment: i never work on this but this information will help you                                  A Meteor package that allows you to attach a schema to a Mongo.Collection. Automatically validates against that schema when inserting and updating from client or server code.

Comment: Yes, you can use enum type in mongoose it seems http://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you are talking about [mongoose schema types](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#built-in-validators) (String).

You have to know that it is possible to add some options when defining a schema type [(options)](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html).

According to what you want to do, the option [enum](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema_string_SchemaString-enum) seems to be a good choice.

*Ps*: enum is a built-in validator, what is a [validator](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#built-in-validators)?

---

### Example from the documentation

```
var states = 'opening open closing closed'.split(' ')
var s = new Schema({ state: { type: String, enum: states }})
```

---

### Your case

```
const CONSTANT_GOOD_VALUES = ['jazz', 'blues', 'rock'];

var artistSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    style: {
        type: String
        enum: CONSTANT_GOOD_VALUES,
    },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :-

```
var artistSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   status: {
        type: String,
        enum : ['jaz,'blues','rock']

    },
});
```